# how to handle push notifications for getting a friend request in android

Tags: android, push-notification

i would like to implement push notifications in android app for friend request and messages like in facebook if user got a friend request or got a message it displays notification exactly same scenario i want to do it ,tried google but didn't find solution,(kindly don't answer me with GCM and PARSE push notifications )give me suitable tutorial links or help me with u r valuable answer ,thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEW ANSWER UPDATED**

Now, you will have to use Firebase Cloud Messaging instead of the old and deprecated GCM: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

**OLD ANSWER:**

The official documentation and the answer to all your questions is here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

> The sections below guide you through the process of setting up a GCM
>   implementation. Before you start, make sure to set up the Google Play
>   Services SDK. You need this SDK to use the GoogleCloudMessaging
>   methods.
>
> Note that a full GCM implementation requires a server-side
>   implementation, in addition to the client implementation in your app.
>   This document offers a complete example that includes both the client
>   and server.

As you ask nothing specific, I cannot gove a better answer for now, please tell us what you don't understand and we might help...

Edit: as requested in comment, this is how you display a notification even when running in background:

```
/**
 * Handling of GCM messages.
 */
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    Context ctx;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
        ctx = context;
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                    intent.getExtras().toString());
        } else {
            sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
        }
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    // Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
                new Intent(ctx, DemoActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
        .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(msg))
        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: In my app i can send a friend request to other users ,other users getting requests but here i want to display a notification for other users even the application is running in the background

Comment: This explained in my link, what don't you understand?